# CommunityToolkit.Mvvm does not generate code on .NET Framework Project

Tags: c#

I'm new to C#. I'm using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm version 8.0.0 with Target framework: .NET Framework 4.7.2.
However, when using an attribute like [ObservableProperty], it did not generate properties.
When i used CommunityToolkit.Mvvm with .NET 6.0, it generated normally.
Did i misunderstand somewhere or this Toolkit does not support .NET Framework.
Sorry for my bad English and thanks a lot.
[image: Error when build]

Comment: What build tool chain (or Visual Studio version) are you using for building the Framework 4.7.2 version of your project? Note that features like the  [ObservableProperty] attribute require code-generation features such as those of the roslyn compiler platform (or derivatives of it), which would not be available in old tools. (CommunityToolkit.Mvvm itself supports projects targetting Framework 4.7.2, but some features of it may still require support of modern build tools to build successfully for older Framework targets)

Comment: i'm using Visual studio 2022 community

Comment: Well then, i guess it would be good to include the relevant error and the code in your question as text (the latter formatted as code block), not as some picture. ("[_Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?_](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question)") Using pictures for such things is generally not an advantage when using this site. That said, i have no clue what else might have been gone wrong there with your project...

Comment: I spent several days for researching more and it seems that: The reason is: "MVVM Toolkit source generators" feature is not available on .NET Framework, and therefore some [Attributes] don't work correctly. I greatly appreciate your help and advice. Thank you !

Comment: Wrong using of a comment - should have been an answer.

Comment: ... Should have been an answer ...

Comment: A little late, but you may find help here:
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73865118/how-to-use-the-source-generators-from-communitytoolkit-mvvm-for-a-net-framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73865118/how-to-use-the-source-generators-from-communitytoolkit-mvvm-for-a-net-framework)